# Calculating the Limits of a Probability Distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

I am trying to understand the mathematics involved in Bayesian Estimation. In particular, I am interested in estimating the Posterior Distribution of the parameter "p" in a Binomial Distribution using the Binomial Likelihood and a Prior based on the Beta Distribution.

Using Baye's Law - the Posterior Distribution can be expressed as follows:

$$\text{Posterior} = \text{Pr}(p | x) = \frac{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} p^{x_i} (1-p)^{1-x_i}\right) \cdot p^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha - 1} \cdot (1-p)^{n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta - 1}}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha)\Gamma(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta)}{\Gamma(n + \alpha + \beta)}} = \frac{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} p^{x_i} (1-p)^{1-x_i}\right) \cdot p^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha - 1} \cdot (1-p)^{n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta - 1}}{\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha)\Gamma(n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta)}{\Gamma(n + \alpha + \beta)}}$$

With the parameter "p" following a data-dependent Beta Distribution:

$$p \sim \text{Beta} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha, n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta\right)$$

**My Question:** In one of my classes, I was told that "when the Prior Beta Distribution has small values of alpha and beta - the Posterior Distribution and the estimated value of "p" will be less influenced by the Prior Distribution and more influenced by the Likelihood". I am trying to understand why this is.

Here is my logic:

- I know that the Expected Value of the Beta Distribution is given by: $$\text{E}[p] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$$
- If we use the above definitions of "alpha and beta" - the Expected Value of the Beta Distribution based on the Posterior Distribution can now be expressed as: $$\text{E}[p] = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha + n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha}{n + \alpha + \beta}$$
- In a Beta Distribution, "alpha and beta" must be greater than 0. Thus, for "very small" values of "alpha and beta", we see that the above formula simply becomes equivalent to the classical Maximum Likelihood Estimation : $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0, \beta \to 0} \text{E}[p] = \lim_{\alpha \to 0, \beta \to 0} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \alpha}{n + \alpha + \beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} = \hat{p}_{\text{MLE}}$$

Thus, I have informally shown that small values of "alpha and beta reduce the impact of the Prior Distribution on the Posterior Estimates".

Is my logic correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is even simpler than resorting to calculation.  The fact that your posterior is $$p \mid \boldsymbol x \sim \operatorname{Beta}(n \bar x + \alpha, n(1-\bar x) + \beta)$$ means that as $\alpha, \beta \to 0^+$, the posterior becomes beta with hyperparameters $n\bar x$ and $n(1-\bar x)$, which does not contain any information from the prior--in a sense, such a posterior is completely determined by the observed data.  As you increase the amount of data observed, $n$ increases, giving more weight to the observed sample mean and decreasing the relative amount of information contributed by the prior.

The choice $\alpha = \beta = 0$ is called an *improper prior* for the Bernoulli-beta model.